# Trying to add clients in a group inside SignalR but not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

When I try to work with groups in SignalR, I have something strange. I did a class for my hub where there's Task which works when I ping all clients. I have done Two methods which one is to add and the second to remove clients from a group. But when I try to had a client inside a group, there's nothing completed.
Here's the code of the hub:

```
public interface IActionClient
{
    // User is in front of the cameras
    Task HighlightUser(Guid userId);
    // When users added or deleted
    Task UpdateGame(int gameId);
    Task JoinGroupAsync(string groupName);
    Task LeaveGroupAsync(string groupName);
}

// possible clients
public enum ClientType
{
    Leaderboard,
    Dashboard,
    Register
}

public class OneHub : Hub<IActionClient>
{
    public OneHub()
    {
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public async Task JoinGroupAsync(string groupName) => await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    public async Task LeaveGroupAsync(string groupName) => await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    // todo : groups 
}
```

And there's when I try to add my clients inside the group:

```
        // add client to group hub
        await _hubClients.Clients.All.JoinGroupAsync(groupName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see their is a way to add user to group base on their connection id like this

```
    public override Task AddGroupAsync(string connectionId, string groupName)
    {
        if (connectionId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionId));
        }

        if (groupName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(groupName));
        }

        var connection = _connections[connectionId];
        if (connection == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        _groups.Add(connection, groupName);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Ref [code](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/1790d6bdf088bab120cd14912d6d625d983fb077/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/DefaultHubLifetimeManager.cs)

Hope it will help